# javascript lines work individually but not in a one after another

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery 3.4.1.  Firing off a function that has 3 lines removing the required attribute.  The fourth line is doing a redirect to another page.  I'm doing the remove attribute just so that it won't flash on the screen that something was required while the redirect happens.  The problem I'm running into is each line works if I run it individually.  If I run the three remove attributes together it works.  If I run 1 remove and the redirect it works.  If I try to run 2 or more of the redirects I don't get any errors but the redirect does not work.

```
$("[id$=txtPositionNumber]").removeAttr("required");
$("[id$=ftpFile]").removeAttr("required");
$("[id$=txtClassIndex]").removeAttr("required");
var x ='http://localhost:9000/Pages/CA/PositionEdit.aspx?tblContractAppointmentPositionID=6;';
$(location).attr("href", x);
```

I didn't know if there was a timing issue or something.. so I tried to add in

```
setTimeout(() => { console.log("World!"); }, 2000);
```

before the redirect.  The setTimeout doesn't fire the console.log when I run everything together.  It works as expected when only part of the code is run.

Anyway.. was wondering what little thing I'm missing.  I understand that I don't need to remove the attributes for the redirect to work but I'd rather not have the user see something flash on the screen.

The asp.net form has the txtPositionNumber, ftpFile andtxtClassIndex. Two of them are textboxes, one is the fileupload control. On the form there is a save button and there is also a dynamically built table that has buttons on each row.  If the save button is clicked we want to take advantage of the html5 requried attribute.  At other times the user may wish to click a button that will take them to another page.  When they click the button, i'd like for the required fields "warning" not to flash before the redirect happens.  That's why I'm trying to remove the attributes before the redirect happens.

Thanks
shannon

Comment: Why do you have `required` attributes if you want to redirect anyway?

Comment: Didn't explain that.  The lines above will be fired off if a certain button on the page is clicked.  The page has other things going on that require the "required" attribute.  thanks

Comment: Then investigate why the said button whose purpose is to redirect, also gives validation errors, Im guessing its inside a form..you can take it outside the form

Comment: It's not clear why you have 3 unique selectors. Why not target all the elements in 1 selector? It's also not clear why you need to remove the `required` attribute when redirecting. This feels like a Problem X, asking Question Y.

Comment: Using one instead of 3 sounds like an idea.  How do i use one line and disable all the required fields on the page.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `input type="submit"` from the button and replace with `input type="button"`. The required action would not fire..

Comment: That's fantastic.. thanks for the help and the explanation.